# Solving Recurrence relation: T(n) = 3T(n/5) + lgn * lgn

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, recurrence

```
Consider the following recurrence
T(n) = 3T(n/5) + lgn * lgn

What is the value of T(n)?

(A) Theta(n ^ log_5{3})
(B) Theta(n ^ log_3{5})
(c) Theta(n Log n )
(D) Theta( Log n )

Answer is (A)
```

My Approach :

lgn * lgn = theta(n) since c2lgn < 2*lglgn < c1*lgn for some n>n0

Above inequality is shown in this picture for c2 = 0.1 and c1 = 1
[image]

log_5{3} < 1,

Hence by master theorem answer has to be theta(n) and none of the answers match. How to solve this problem??

Comment: `lgn * lgn = theta(n)` - no,

Comment: Thanks amit the mistake I had done was to restrict x coordinate to limited values. I extended range of x and got to know my mistake!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your claim that lg n * lg n = Θ(n) is false. Notice that the limit of (lg n)<sup>2</sup> / n tends toward 0 as n goes to infinity. You can see this using l'Hopital's rule:

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (lg n)<sup>2</sup> / n
>
> = lim <sub>n → ∞</sub> 2 lg n / n
>
> = lim <sub>n → ∞</sub> 2 / n
>
> = 0

More generally, using similar reasoning, you can prove that lg n = o(n<sup>ε</sup>) for any ε > 0.

Let's try to solve this recurrence using the master theorem. We see that there are three subproblems of size n / 5 each, so we should look at the value of log<sub>5</sub> 3. Since (lg n)<sup>2</sup> = o(n<sup>log<sub>5</sub> 3</sup>), we see that the recursion is bottom-heavy and can conclude that the recurrence solves to O(n<sup>log<sub>5</sub> 3</sup>), which is answer (A) in your list up above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

To apply **Master Theorem** we should check the relation between

n<sup>log<sub>5</sub>(3)</sup> ~= n<sup>0.682</sup> and (lg(n))<sup>2</sup>

Unfortunately lg(n)<sup>2</sup> != 2*lg(n): it is lg(n<sup>2</sup>) that's equal to 2*lg(n)

Also, there is a big difference, in Master Theorem, if f(n) is O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>(a)-ε</sup>), or instead Θ(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>): if the former holds we can apply case 1, if the latter holds case 2 of the theorem.

With just a glance, it looks highly unlikely (lg(n))<sup>2</sup> = Ω(n<sup>0.682</sup>), so let's try to prove that (lg(n))<sup>2</sup> = O(n<sup>0.682</sup>), i.e.:

∃ n<sub>0</sub>, c ∈ N<sup>+</sup>, such that for n>n<sub>0</sub>, (lg(n))<sup>2</sup> < c * n<sup>0.682</sup>

Let's take the square root of both sides (assuming n > 1, the inequality holds)

lg(n) < c<sub>1</sub> * n<sup>0.341</sup> , (where c<sub>1</sub> = sqrt(c))

now we can assume, that lg(n) = log<sub>2</sub>(n) (otherwise the multiplicative factor could be absorbed by our constant - as you know constant factors don't matter in asymptotic analysis) and exponentiate both sides:

2<sup>lg(n)</sup> < 2<sup>c<sub>2</sub> * n<sup>0.341</sup></sup> <=> n < 2<sup>c<sub>2</sub> * n<sup>0.341</sup></sup> <=> n < (n<sup>2<sup>0.341</sup></sup>)<sup>c<sub>2</sub></sup> <=> n < (n<sup>2<sup>0.341</sup></sup>)<sup>c<sub>2</sub></sup> <=> n < (n<sup>1.266</sup>)<sup>c<sub>2</sub></sup>

which is immediately true choosing c<sub>2</sub> = 1 and n<sub>0</sub> = 1

Therefore, it does hold true that f(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>(a)-ε</sup>), and we can apply case 1 of the **Master Theorem**, and conclude that:

T(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>5</sub>3</sup>)

Same result, a bit more formally.